# Why doesn't this replace function work?

Tags: python, string, python-2.7, escaping

So I'm using this line of Python to replace some weird characters in a string;

```
title = title.replace('\xc3', 'e').replace('\xa9', 's')
```

The weird string is:

"B\xc3\xa9same Mucho"

It has some Spanish-style accents, and I figured it would be simpler to try to get rid of them instead of trying to implement the accents.

But it doesn't replace the affected parts.

What's wrong with the line?

Thanks!

evamvid

Comment: Works as given on Python 2.7.6. Also, what do you mean "implement the accents"?

Comment: what output are you getting? I'm getting `Bésame Mucho` initially, and `Bessame Mucho` after the replace.

Comment: What do you mean *trying to implement the accents*? The accents are already implemented here. Python just represents them in their escaped form. Compare `print title` to `print repr(title)`. Also keep in mind how they appear depends on your terminal font.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you're using Python 2.7, you're just having a [classic bad encoding day](https://docs.python.org/2/howto/unicode.html). Python 2 is a little notorious for its Unicode(De|En)codeError. If you really want to replace those characters, observe that:

```
>>> utitle = title.decode('utf-8')
u'B\xe9same Mucho'
```

so

```
>>> utitle.replace(u'\xe9', 'e')
u'Besame Mucho'
```

But you really want to be dealing with unicode the whole time, and the characters there are really fine, so just do the `decode`.

This is one area in which Python 3 is much better than Python 2.